# How to break a while loop using rowcount in sybase db?

Tags: sql, sybase

I am trying to run a loop and exec a stored proc for each however. However, I am not sure why the loop does not break if rowcount is 3.

I have only 3 rows in the products table. I want below to break after reading 3 rows.

```
declare @brand varchar(20)
declare @loc varchar(20)
declare @val int

SET ROWCOUNT 3
while(1=1)
BEGIN
   select TOP 1 @brand=u.brand_name, @loc= u.loc, @val = u.value
              from products;
   IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
      BREAK
   --Exec stored proc here 
END
GO
```

Comment: are you deleting each row from the `products` table after it has been processed? if the answer is 'no' then ... your table will always have 3 rows, `select top 1` will always find 1 row, `@@rowcount` will always equal `1`, the `break` will never be performed and you'll be stuck in an endless loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop over 3 rows, you will need to use a cursor. Something like this:

```
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR 
SELECT top 3 brand_name, loc, val
FROM products

OPEN cursor1

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @brand, @loc, @val

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- do something here
  
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @brand, @loc, @val

END

CLOSE cursor1
DEALLOCATE cursor1
```